# PHP: usort files / speed

Tags: php, arrays, file, sorting, directory

I am looking for a way to sort an array of objects based on two factors.
This is my current usort implementation:

```
usort($contents, function($a, $b) {
    $aN = $a->getName();
    $bN = $b->getName();

    $aD = $a->isDirectory();
    $bD = $b->isDirectory();

    switch(true) {
        case  $aD && !$bD: return -1;
        case !$aD &&  $bD: return +1;
        default:
            return strcmp($aN, $bN); // Edited
    }
});
```

As you might have guessed, the objects represent files, however for this example, only the `->getName` and `->isDirectory` methods are relevant.

This example I have create does work, however I tested it on a collection of 9000 files, and this block alone increased the time of the general process from 1 second to around 3.

The sorting it is doing is fairly simple:

- Directories first in alphanumerical order.
- Files second in alphanumerical order.

I am looking for a way to improve it, or find an alternative.

If it is to anyones interest, this is the source of the `$contents` array:

```
$path = $this->compute($path);
$dir  = opendir($path);

$contents = array();

while(false !== $name = readdir($dir)) {
    if($name == '.' || $name == '..') {
        continue;
    }

    $contents[] = new LocalFile($this->directory, sprintf('%s/%s', $path, $name));
}

return $contents;
```

However this process takes very little time, I would be interested to discover that sorting can be accomplishing during the reading of a directory.

Side note, I have read I can use `DirectoryIterator` by extending it and performing comparisons, but I am not sure that is a lot different to what I am doing right now.

Comment: Why are you doing a sort inside a sort callback?

Comment: Why not dump your file list to a [SPLHeap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splheap.construct.php) instead of putting them in an array and then usorting the array

Comment: @Jack Its my lame solution to alphanumerically sort a pair of strings when the pair are either both directories or files.

Comment: @Flosculus - just use [strcmp()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) instead of that nested sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sorting logic could be simplified to just this:

```
    if (($a_isdir = $a->isDirectory()) != $b->isDirectory()) {
        // either a is directory and b is not, or the other way around
        return $a_isdir ? -1 : 1;
    }

    // a and b are either both directories or files
    // compare normally
    return strcmp($a->getName(), $b->getName());
```

Additionally, as mentioned by Mark, you can extend [`SplHeap`](http://php.net/splheap) by implementing the above logic inside `::compare($a, $b)` and have the list of objects sorted as you insert them.